# How can I use a Keras trained model saved in a HDF5 file to make predictions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, prediction

I recently got started with neural networks. I built a handwritten character prediction model using the extended MNIST dataset, sklearn, Keras, numpy and pandas. The main goal is to take and/or upload pictures of handwritten text/characters and the model should be able to guess.

After finishing the training phase, the model was saved in the file `my_model.h5`. At this point, how could I use this trained model (specifically, the `my_model.h5`) in a Python program that receives as input images and should produce a prediction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to load a (trained) model from a file in Keras and TensorFlow.

The [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/) provides a snippet that shows how to load a model.

```
from keras.models import load_model

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

After having loaded the model, you can use [`model.predict`](https://keras.io/models/model/).

You integrate this code into your application as you wish.